# É muito custoso fazer uma busca diretamente pela key?

Tags: javascript

```
var products = {};

for(var i = 0; i < 300; i++){
    products["product" + (i + 1)] = {}
    products["product" + (i + 1)]["qtd" + (i + 1)] = i + 1
}

//Busca pela key
console.log(products["product" + 400]); //undefined
console.log(products["product" + 299]); //{qtd299: 299}
console.log(products["product" + 22]); //{qtd22: 22}
console.log(products["product" + 301]); //undefined
//Assim fica até mais fácil fazer a busca:
if(products.product400){
    if(products.product400.qtd400){
    console.log(products["product" + 400]["qtd400"]);//não acha
    }
}
if(products.product200){
    if(products.product200.qtd200){
    console.log(products["product" + 200]["qtd200"]);//200
    }
}

//Busca fazendo loop
console.log(search("product" + 400))//null
console.log(search("product" + 299)) //{qtd299: 299}
console.log(search("product" + 22)) //{qtd22: 22}
console.log(search("product" + 301)) //null

function search(name){
    for (var k in products) {
        if (k == name) {       
            return products[k];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mw8v9jkf/

Quais são as melhores abordagens? É uma boa prática fazer a primeira abordagem?
No segundo modo eu preciso criar um loop pra percorrer o objeto...

Comment: Na dúvida você sempre pode [testar qual é o mais rápido](https://jsperf.com/pesquisar-objeto-por-chave-ou-por-for/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A abordagem ideal depende do conhecimento que você possui a respeito das propriedades do objeto javascript. Se você conhece o nome da propriedade, a melhor abordagem é acessá-la com o `.`. Dessa forma, nenhuma consulta precisa ser feita pois você acessa diretamente a propriedade do objeto:

```
//Busca pela key
console.log(products.product400); //undefined
console.log(products.product299); //{qtd299: 299}
console.log(products.product22); //{qtd22: 22}
console.log(products.product301); //undefined
```

Se você não sabe o nome da propridade do objeto, aí sim você pode usar os `[]` para acessar as propriedades dinamicamente, utilizando a busca pela key (sua alternativa 1). Na alternativa 2, você simplesmente está reimplementando a busca de propriedades num objeto Javascript, e por isso, a melhor abordagem é usar o acesso via key (`[]`), que já é nativo.